# PDO действия с таблицами

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php, mysql, sql

Есть таблицы для каждого юзера на сайте. Как используя PDO выполнить такой код?

```
$user = 3;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'admin', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pre = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_? ORDER BY id DESC');
$exe = $pre->execute(array( $user ));
$return = $pre->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$db = null;
return $return;
```

Сам он ругается

> Error!: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3' ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЕМНИП, имя таблицы автоматически подставлять нельзя в prepare. Можно сделать так:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM user_'.$user.' ORDER BY id DESC';
```

В execute(), соответственно, аргумент с $user уже будет не нужен.